# React js framer motion AnimatePresence not work on Exit

Tags: reactjs, transition, exit

**Framer** motion animation doesn't work on exit, Its works fine on Initial and  animate but it's not working on exit

I am using framer motion =>"framer-motion": "^7.0.0",

```
return (
   <>
     <  AnimatePresence>
       {props.profile && (
         <motion.div
           initial={{ opacity: 0 }}
           animate={{ opacity: 1 }}
           exit={{ opacity: 0 }}
           transition={{ duration: 0.3 }}
           className={css.overlay}
         ></motion.div>
       )}
     </  AnimatePresence>
     <  AnimatePresence>
       {props.profile && (
         <motion.div
           className={css.profile}
           initial={{
             opacity: 0,
             top: "-200px",
             transform: "translate(-50%,-50%)",
           }}
           animate={{
             opacity: 1,
             top: "50%",
           }}
           exit={{ opacity: 0, top: "-200px" }}
           transition={{ duration: 0.5 }}
         >
some code
</motion.div>
     </  AnimatePresence>
</>
)
```

thank you for help

Comment: Could you please provide a Codesandbox for further investigations?

Answer (score 0):

Code inside component is absolutely fine

I just made mistake while I am using it

```
{ profile && <Profile setProfile={setProfile} profile={profile} /> }
```

I fix it just removing  conditon

```
<Profile setProfile={setProfile} profile={profile} />
```